# Multiple External Interrupt on LPC1768 : only one interrupt is working

Tags: c, arm, interrupt, cortex-m

I've wrote code for external interrupt EINT1.  That works, but if I want to add a second interrupt (EINT3), only the new works.  I can have the both.

Here under is my code, may be I'm wrong but I do not see where.  Can you help me?

```
      printuart(14,"SLEEP MODE ON");          
      EINTInit();   

      LPC_SC->PCON &= ~(0x03 <<0); 

      flagwakeup=0;

      while(flagwakeup==0)
          checkwdt_ev(); //reset watchdog

    NVIC_DisableIRQ(EINT1_IRQn);

    LPC_PINCON->PINSEL4 &= ~(0x03 << 22);   //as gpio
    LPC_GPIO2->FIODIR &= ~(0x01 <<11);  // as input
    LPC_PINCON->PINSEL2 &= ~(0x03<<26); // P2.13 as GPIO
    LPC_GPIO2->FIODIR &=~(1<<13);   //P2.13 as input

    printuart(16,"SLEEP MODE OFF");


uint32_t EINTInit( void )
{
 LPC_PINCON->PINSEL4 &= ~(3UL<<22); // Reset P2.11  to GPIO
 LPC_PINCON->PINSEL4 |= (0x01<<22); // P2.11 as external interupt

 LPC_PINCON->PINSEL4 &= ~(3UL<<26); // Reset P2.13  to GPIO
 LPC_PINCON->PINSEL4 |= (0x01<<26); // P2.13 as external interupt

 LPC_GPIOINT->IO2IntEnF = ((0x01 <<11) | (0x01 <<13));   //Port2.11 and P2.13 are  falling edge.


 LPC_SC->EXTMODE = (EINT1_EDGE | EINT3_EDGE) ;      //INT1 and INT3 edge trigger

 LPC_SC->EXTPOLAR = 0;              //INT1 and INT3 is falling edge by default



 NVIC_EnableIRQ(EINT1_IRQn);

 return( TRUE );
}



void EINT1_IRQHandler (void)

{
  LPC_SC->EXTINT = EINT1;       /* clear interrupt */

  LPC_SC->PCONP |= (0x01 <<3);      //power on uart0
  LPC_SC->PCONP |= (0x01 <<4);      //power on uart1
  LPC_SC->PCONP |= (0x01 <<7);      //power on i2c0
  LPC_SC->PCONP |= (0x01 <<8);      //power on SPI
  LPC_SC->PCONP |= (0x01 <<10);     //power on SSP1
  LPC_SC->PCONP |= (0x01 <<19);     //power on i2c1
  LPC_SC->PCONP |= (0x01 <<21);     //ppower on SSP0
  LPC_SC->PCONP |= (0x01 <<26);     //power on i2c2

  //test2_count_fhn(15,"SLEEP MODE OFF");

  flagwakeup=1;

}
```

I have also try another and I've the same result :

```
    printuart(14,"SLEEP MODE ON");


              EINTInit();   //external interrupt for wake up after sleep mode
              EINT3Init();

              LPC_SC->PCON &= ~(0x03 <<0); 
              flagwakeup=0;

              while(flagwakeup==0)
                  checkwdt_ev(); //reset watchdog

            NVIC_DisableIRQ(EINT1_IRQn);
            NVIC_DisableIRQ(EINT3_IRQn);
            LPC_PINCON->PINSEL4 &= ~(0x03 << 22);   //as gpio
            LPC_GPIO2->FIODIR &= ~(0x01 <<11);  // as input
            LPC_PINCON->PINSEL2 &= ~(0x03<<26); // P2.13 as GPIO
            LPC_GPIO2->FIODIR &=~(1<<13);   //P2.13 as input

            printuart(16,"SLEEP MODE OFF");




    uint32_t EINTInit( void )

    {
      LPC_PINCON->PINSEL4 &= ~(3UL<<22);    // Reset P2.11  to GPIO
      LPC_PINCON->PINSEL4 |= (0x01<<22);    // P2.11 as external interupt

      LPC_GPIOINT->IO2IntEnF = (0x01 <<11); //Port2.11 is falling edge.


      LPC_SC->EXTMODE = EINT1_EDGE ;        // INT1 edge trigger

      LPC_SC->EXTPOLAR = 0;             // INT1 is falling edge by default



      NVIC_EnableIRQ(EINT1_IRQn);

      return( TRUE );

    }


    uint32_t EINT3Init( void )

    {
      LPC_PINCON->PINSEL4 &= ~(3UL<<26);    // Reset P2.13  to GPIO
      LPC_PINCON->PINSEL4 |= (0x01<<26);    // P2.13 as external interupt





      LPC_GPIOINT->IO2IntEnF |= (0x01 <<13);    //Port2.13 is falling edge.

      LPC_SC->EXTMODE |= EINT3_EDGE;        // INT3 edge trigger 

      LPC_SC->EXTPOLAR = 0;             //INT1 is falling edge by default */



      NVIC_EnableIRQ(EINT3_IRQn);

      return( TRUE );

    }



    void EINT3_IRQHandler (void)

    {
      LPC_SC->EXTINT = EINT3;       //clear interrupt 


      LPC_SC->PCONP |= (0x01 <<3);      //power on uart0
      LPC_SC->PCONP |= (0x01 <<4);      //power on uart1
      LPC_SC->PCONP |= (0x01 <<7);      //power on i2c0
      LPC_SC->PCONP |= (0x01 <<8);      //power on SPI
      LPC_SC->PCONP |= (0x01 <<10);     //power on SSP1
      LPC_SC->PCONP |= (0x01 <<19);     //power on i2c1
      LPC_SC->PCONP |= (0x01 <<21);     //ppower on SSP0
      LPC_SC->PCONP |= (0x01 <<26);     //power on i2c2


      flagwakeup=1;

    }

    void EINT1_IRQHandler (void)

    {
      LPC_SC->EXTINT = EINT1;       //clear interrupt 

      LPC_SC->PCONP |= (0x01 <<3);      //power on uart0
      LPC_SC->PCONP |= (0x01 <<4);      //power on uart1
      LPC_SC->PCONP |= (0x01 <<7);      //power on i2c0
      LPC_SC->PCONP |= (0x01 <<8);      //power on SPI
      LPC_SC->PCONP |= (0x01 <<10);     //power on SSP1
      LPC_SC->PCONP |= (0x01 <<19);     //power on i2c1
      LPC_SC->PCONP |= (0x01 <<21);     //ppower on SSP0
      LPC_SC->PCONP |= (0x01 <<26);     //power on i2c2

      flagwakeup=1;

}
```

I suppose that my problem is in the init of the interrupt (?)

If someone can help me,

thanks

Comment: Is it possible that NVIC_EnableIRQ takes a bitmask? (ie IRQ1|IRQ3)

Comment: no this function takes only the positive number of the external interrupt to enable.

I've tried with :
`NVIC_EnableIRQ(EINT1_IRQn);
 NVIC_EnableIRQ(EINT3_IRQn);
`But this is the same effect, only EINT1 works

Comment: I don't know how you verify that the other irq is functional, as I don't see anywhere this kind of call `NVIC_SetVector(EINT1_IRQn, EINT1_IRQHandler);`

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen SetVector dont need to be called if startup code defines the mapping for vector table.